# Executor service returning incorrect response

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice, callable

I am creating future list from a list of calls to executor service submit method based on student ID. The response from service is not returning for all studentId's. It runs for the right number of times but the studentId getting used in service call is either first or last. It is ignoring the middle ones. Please check the code below

```
private List<Student> studentTask() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        List<Future<List<Student>>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int studentNumber = 1; studentNumber <= 10; studentNumber++) {
            Callable<List<Student>> task = new StudentService(studentNumber);
            Future<List<Student>> recordTask = executor.submit(task);
            tasks.add(recordTask);
        }
        try {
            for (Future<List<Student>> future : tasks) {
                List<Student> student = future.get();
                //...
            }
            return //studentList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

private class StudentService implements Callable<List<Student>>{
   private int studentId;
    
   StudentService(int studentId){
     this.studentId = studentId;
   }
    
   public List<Student> call(){
     return getStudentNames(this.studentId);
   }
 }

public class Student{
   private String studentName;
   private int StudentId;

   //Parameterized Constructor
}

private List<Student> getStudentNames(int studentId){
   List<Student> studentList = // db call returning all student with 
                               // respect to studentId.
   return studentList;
}
```

In the below code the service is getting called 10 times but for only student Id **1** and **10**. Not able to get result of **2** to **9** which is resulting in an inaccurate result.
Need help in understanding if i am missing anything here.

Comment: Please post the complete code, what is 'studentList' in the call method?

Comment: Your code does not compile. `StudentService` takes a `String` in its constructor, but you pass a `int` primitive. Your class definition of `StudentService` should not have parens before the outer curly braces.

Comment: Updated the question. Added StudentService and made compilable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is faulty to the point of not compiling, as noted in [my Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72438256/executor-service-returning-incorrect-response#comment127973207_72438256). And you've omitted some possibly important code. So I cannot diagnose exactly what problems you have. So I will revamp your code in my own style, and get it working.

Rather than trying to fill a list of `Future` objects, I would fill a list of tasks, either `Runnable` or `Callable` objects. You can then call `ExecutorService#invokeAll` to submit all the tasks. You get back a list of `Future` objects to track the completion of your submitted tasks.

First, let's define the `Student` class as a [record](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```
record Student( int number , String name ) { }
```

It seems to me you have mixed two different responsibilities into the `StudentService` class. That class should focus only on holding the students’s data. That class should *not* be the `Callable`. Define the `Callable` separately, and pass the `StudentService` object to its constructor.

Notice that we return an `Optional`. If the calling programmer provides an invalid student ID, we return an empty Optional rather than a null pointer.

```java
class StudentService
{
    private Set < Student > students;

    StudentService ( )
    {
        this.students =
                Set.of(
                        new Student( 1 , "Alice" ) ,
                        new Student( 2 , "Bob" ) ,
                        new Student( 3 , "Carol" ) ,
                        new Student( 4 , "Davis" ) ,
                        new Student( 5 , "Ernestine" ) ,
                        new Student( 6 , "Frank" ) ,
                        new Student( 7 , "Gail" ) ,
                        new Student( 8 , "Harold" ) ,
                        new Student( 9 , "Iris" ) ,
                        new Student( 10 , "Jean-Luc" )
                );
    }

    synchronized Optional < Student > fetchStudentById ( final int id )
    {
        return this.students.stream().filter( student -> student.id() == id ).findAny();
    }
}
```

Notice in code above that the `fetchStudentById` is marked `synchronized`. We know this method will be invoked across threads. The current implementation here may be thread-safe, by streaming over a non-modifiable `List`. But in real work, this look-up may not be thread-safe. So we mark it `synchronized` for thread-safety.

If you are not comfortable with streams as seen in that code above, know that you could accomplish the same effect with a conventional loop. Using streams makes for briefer code, but the use of streams here is *not* important.

Define our task, a `Callable` that looks up a student by ID, and returns a `Optional < Student >`. We pass to its constructor the `StudentService` object to be used to actually find the student. And we pass the id of the desired student.

```java
class StudentFindingTask implements Callable < Optional < Student > >
{
    private final StudentService studentService;
    private final int studentId;

    public StudentFindingTask ( final StudentService studentService , int studentId )
    {
        this.studentService = studentService;
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional < Student > call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        return this.studentService.fetchStudentById( this.studentId );
    }
}
```

Now we are ready to try this out.

Instantiate a `StudentService` object to be used by all our tasks.

```java
StudentService studentService = new StudentService();
```

Establish a list of task objects. Pass the service and id to each.

```java
int limit = 10;
List < StudentFindingTask > tasks = new ArrayList <>( limit );
for ( int studentId = 1 ; studentId <= limit ; studentId++ )
{
    tasks.add( new StudentFindingTask( studentService , studentId ) );
}
```

Prepare the executor service, and the list of `Future` objects we expect it to fill.

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 5 );
List < Future < Optional < Student > > > futures;
```

Submit all those tasks to the executor service.

```java
try { futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
```

Shutdown the executor service, and wait for results. The following is boilerplate code taken from Javadoc, and slightly modified.

```java
executorService.shutdown(); // Stop accepting task submissions.
try
{
    if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
    {
        executorService.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
        if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
        { System.err.println( "Pool did not terminate" ); }
    }
}
catch ( InterruptedException ex )
{
    executorService.shutdownNow();
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Lastly, report the results of our tasks by examining each `Future` object. In real work, you would likely interrogate the future for its completion status, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

```java
for ( Future < Optional < Student > > future : futures )
{
    try { System.out.println( future.get() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); } catch ( ExecutionException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
}
```

When run.

```
Optional[Student[id=1, name=Alice]]
Optional[Student[id=2, name=Bob]]
Optional[Student[id=3, name=Carol]]
Optional[Student[id=4, name=Davis]]
Optional[Student[id=5, name=Ernestine]]
Optional[Student[id=6, name=Frank]]
Optional[Student[id=7, name=Gail]]
Optional[Student[id=8, name=Harold]]
Optional[Student[id=9, name=Iris]]
Optional[Student[id=10, name=Jean-Luc]]
```

Comment: I have edited the question above. I was able to get the response using the executor service as mentioned above in your answer, the threads are always getting called for first and last value of student ID 10 times.

Comment: Have fixed the issue, I was using the same instance of student Id in the for loop while adding the task. Should have created a new object with new student Id.

Comment: @SSharma2203 No, that cannot be the issue, not according to the code shown in your Question. In the loop adding tasks, `studentNumber` is an `int` primitive, not an object. And that `int` increments on each loop.